# Spring security check error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my new web application I had used bootstrap for creating a login form in the header.

When I try to login the result is always the redirect to error page and I don't understand why. The log and the console of chrome don't give me any errors.

I suppose it's corny, but I do not see the solution.
Any Ideas?

My code:

**header.jspx**

```
    <div id="header" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">

  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl"/>
    <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_check" var="form_url" />

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only"></span> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home" style="font-weight: bold;">MY PROJECT NAME</a>

            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal != null}">
                        <sec:authentication property="principal.username" var="username" />
                        <span style="float: right; border-left: 1px solid #c6d0da;"><a
                            href="${logoutUrl}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">&#160;</span>
                        </a></span>
                        <li><a href="${showLoggedUserUrl}${username}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&#160;</span>${username}
                        </a></li>
                    </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="navbar-right">
                                <div class="btn-group "> 
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" data-toggle="dropdown"> Login <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <form:form name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST" class="">

                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div >Accedi:</div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback has-error" >
                                            <input id="j_username" type='text' class="form-control input-sm" name='j_username' placeholder="Errore Username"  />
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback has-error" >
                                                    <input id="j_password" type='password' name='j_password' placeholder="Errore Password" class="form-control input-sm" />
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Accedi</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form:form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="navbar-right">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" data-toggle="dropdown"> Login <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <form:form name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST" class="">

                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div >Accedi:</div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div class="form-group has-feedback" >
                                            <input id="j_username" type='text' class="form-control input-sm" name='j_username' placeholder="Username"  />
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group has-feedback" >
                                                    <input id="j_password" type='password' name='j_password' placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-sm" />
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div >
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="proceed">Accedi</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form:form>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/" 
            authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=t" />
        <!-- authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/> -->

        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management>

    </http>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="it.myproject.security.core.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

    <!-- Enable controller method level security -->
    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:org/springframework/security/messages"/>
    </beans:bean>

 </beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
....
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you narrow down your JSP to the problematic code and post some stacktrace. Enable debug logging for Spring-security and then post the stacktrace. Without that, it's difficult to isolate and identify the issue.

Comment: Spring security uses `username` and `password` (by default) as the names for the field, yours are prefixed with `j_` (representing the defaults of older Spring Security versions).

Comment: Although you have found the solution - in situation like these I found it really handy to put the spring security logging in debug mode. Spring security does quite good job logging all important information and reason as to why it outputs a success/failure view.